# Is there a way an app can be notified that a fingerprint from a device has been deregistered?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, biometrics

I'm a beginner to Flutter and programming in general.

First I'd like to know if it's possible to notify the creator of an app or it's back end service that a fingerprint has been deregistered and a new one added.

**Note**: The objective is **not** to get fingerprint data but to uniquely identify people in one way or the other. For example assuming an app would like to manage dormitories that have a closing time of say 9 pm and intends to generate a report of everyone present inside by using their device location and a service on a local network that checks location data and asks for a fingerprint authentication, there's every possibility that users could leave their devices to other users and register their fingerprints as well allowing them to provide authentication and creating inaccurate reports for the dormitory.

Please any suggestions for the above situation?

Comment: All you can know from your report is that the device is located inside the dormitory. You can't know anything about the owner's location. My suggestion is that if you need to know that the person is there then someone will need to physically sight that person or make them present their fingerprint to a device that *you control*; there are employee "time clock" devices that could be used for this purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no support for "detecting de-registration" directly. Even if it were, it would not be useful.

**tldr;** Access, guarded by a device-secret fingerprint or otherwise, *from an arbitrary and uncontrolled device* cannot be used to guarantee that the person who 'owns' the device is present. It is the data governance regulations (EULA, company/dorm policy, etc.) and *trust* in the user to adhere to such, including reporting violations, which allows the device-to-person assertion.

On a mobile device, fingerprint authentication is effectively a **per-device secret than can *accept any of the registered fingerprints* which is used to protect other access/secrets**.

Consider:

- Fingerprints are *not* accessible directly by applications and thus *cannot* be used as "user IDs".

  Each device uses a private per-device key to encrypt and store the fingerprint information. This information is not accessible externally nor is it uploaded.

  See 'Secure Enclave' for iOS and 'Trusted Execution Environment' for Android.
- A person can have multiple fingerprints registered per device. This implies that *multiple fingerprints from different people can be added and there is no way to determine the difference*. Likewise, a person could register a fingerprint for a different finger on multiple devices.
- The encoding of a fingerprint is a "one way" data modeling that *accepts* the fingerprint as registered. The actual fingerprint data will differ, even before it's securely saved: it is only the application of this model onto the fingerprint pattern being applied that is useful.

---

Now, if there was a *physically controlled* device / system ..

An example of a *physically controlled* system might be usages of fixed terminals controlling single-person entry/exit doors (with security cameras and/or a physical guard) where people can only register a fingerprint in front of a trusted person after appropriate ID verification.. how much does it really matter? And what happens when a person climbs through a window?

Having the app take a detailed face / eye scan off a live camera and sending it in to a controlled server for some internal biometric-based verification might be some [draconian] half-way step .. I'd say "No Thanks" ;-)

Answer (score 0):

On iOS, if something is protected by fingerprint or faceID, the developer can set an option that the data can only be accessed if the set of registered fingerprints/ faces is unchanged. So you could send a one-time code that the user puts in their keychain, and if the change registered fingerprints, it’s gone. Now if I registered fingerprints of myself and my three best mates, you can’t detect that.

Comment: how is that possible to implement ? Any link of docs you can reference? Thank you.